# how can I make svglite render portable svgs on travis-ci?

Tags: r, fonts, r-markdown, travis-ci, svglite

Plots rendered through [svglite](https://github.com/r-lib/svglite) look differently when rendered through Travis, then when rendered locally.

This happens, because my **local machine** (macOS in this case) aliases different (more standard?) fonts for the default R plots

```
gdtools::match_family("Arial")
## [1] "Arial"
gdtools::match_family("sans")
## [1] "Bitstream Vera Sans"
```

... than **travis ci**:

```
gdtools::match_family("Arial")
## [1] "Liberation Sans"
gdtools::match_family("sans")
## [1] "DejaVu Sans"
```

"Liberation Sans", in turn, is not necessarily available on all computers viewing the svg (it wasn't on mine, until I ran `brew cask install font-liberation-sans`).

**So, while the locally-generated SVGs have pretty decent portability (~"Arial"), the TravisCI-generated (~"Liberation Sans") do not.**

I'd like rock-solid portability that works on every computer with a reasonable current browser.
I understand from [svglite fonts vignette](http://r-lib.github.io/svglite/articles/fonts.html) that I should probably use *User font aliases* to accomplish this, but I have not managed to get it to work, and am pretty confused about the whole font businesses.

**I just want SVGs from svglite that look the same everywhere.**

Here's the boilerplate `index.Rmd` that creates the different plots.

````
---
title: "index"
author: "foo"
date: "11/2/2018"
output:
  rmarkdown::html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# `png` Device

```{r png, echo=FALSE, dev = 'png'}
plot(pressure)
```


# `svg` Device

```{r svg, echo=FALSE, dev = 'svg'}
plot(pressure)
```


# `svglite` Device

```{r svglite, echo=FALSE, dev = 'svglite'}
plot(pressure)
```
````

(The entire repo and travis builds is [here](https://github.com/maxheld83/rmdbpl), finished website is at http://datascience.phil.fau.de/rmdbpl/).

When rendered locally (macOS) all three plots look roughly the same:

[image: rendered locally]

When build on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/maxheld83/rmdbpl), the plot rendered through svglite, *viewed on a machine without "Liberation Sans"* will substitute a *serif* fonts, which looks bad.

[image: travis]

Comment: if anyone has enough points to add an `svglite` tag to this question, that'd be great.

Comment: Max of 5 tags regardless of rep

Comment: Have you tried adding `gdtools::match_family("Arial")` to an R code block in the Rmd and seeing what it says? Also, have you tried installing any OS font packages (Travis-CI base builds are pretty bare-bones)

Comment: @hrbrmstr ah, yes of course – I cut it down to 4 tags, one available for `svglite` now.

Comment: @hrbrmstr great idea, thanks, hadn't thought about it. Updated in the above, but it doesn't seem like the root of the problem to me, b/c all aliases look pretty sans-serif.
But I don't get all this font business, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Ah, so I'm wondering, now, if you're viewing the svglite-generated document on a system _without_ Liberation Sans. What happens if you install https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/liberation-sans on the OS you're viewing the generated HTML document from?

Comment: yikes, yes, that solves the problem (on my machine), thanks @hrbrmstr, but still doesn't exactly make the svg portable. Going to update the question accordingly.

Comment: Right. You'll need to specify an actual font like "Helvetica" which is more universal and ensure Helvetica is installed in your travis config